# Macro triggered by cell selection

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro 'Edit_Row' that brings the values from the active row into a UserForm for editing. This macro is called by another macro, which is triggered by selecting the cell in column B of the table for the appropriate row:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Selection.Count = 1 Then
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B3:B9999")) Is Nothing Then
        Call Edit_Row
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

**This works as intended, except for the fact that this macro is also activated any time a sort is done on the table.** Is there something else that I can do to achieve the same result (without these false positives)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table's `Range` includes the headers in Row 3, try something like this:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim tbl As ListObject
Set tbl = Me.ListObjects("Table1")  'Modify using your table's Name

If Target.Cells.Count <> 1 Then Exit Sub

If Not Intersect(Target, tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(2)) Is Nothing Then
    Call Edit_Row
End If

End Sub
```

Note: If your table doesn't begin in column A, then modify `.Columns(2)` to `.Columns(1)`.

The way this should work is that it's checking whether `Selection` is part of the table's `DataBodyRange`, which excludes the header row.